# Remove Right Click Area on Lenovo ThinkPad W540

Tags: windows-7, touchpad, thinkpad, regedit

The Lenovo ThinkPad W540 does away with dedicated buttons for the trackpad and instead the whole trackpad area is clickable.

The lack of any buttons to feel, coupled with the fact that trackpad is off center (to the left) means I frequently will mistakenly click on the right half of the trackpad when I want to left click.

I'd like to make this behave exactly like a Mac instead - what has traditionally been a "right click" should only be activated through a two finger click or through a key press + a one finger click. One finger clicking anywhere on the trackpad should act as a "left click".

I have gone through all of the settings exposed through the control panel and none of them helped. I've also tried changing a bunch of values in the registry but nothing I did seemed to change this behavior (fortunately I made a backup before I started tinkering around with it, and I restored after concluding nothing I did helped. And before someone asks, yes, I did reset my computer after each change in the registry.)

The computer is running Windows 7.

Comment: I should mention that at some point between when I asked this and today, the problem stopped occurring. Like most irritating problems, I didn't really notice when it stopped, but I can confirm that it definitely doesn't happen anymore. I don't think anything I did in regedit in the past 13 months fixed this... but I may have updated drivers for the trackpad or something that fixed it. If anyone else still has the problems I described in this post, comment and we can try to figure out what's different between my machine and yours to identify what fixed it for me, and then we can fix it for you.